# Is there a systematic way to find the gerneral formula of partial sum of a series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Recently, I was working on *Principles of real analysis* by Rudin. When I got into the topic of convergence of series (Ch3), the book said if partial sum of the series converge, then the series converge.

And, an idea popped into my head that if there is a systematic way to find out the formula of the partial sum, like geometric series does, so I can test the convergence of the series simply by showing that the limit of the formula and does not need to use so many tests, like comparison test, ratio test, root test, etc.

Comment: This is no easy task, bro. This is the definition of a series, isn't it?

Comment: Sometimes there is, in general there isn't.  When there is, then yes of course you can try to reason about the expression that you manipulate the sum into.

Comment: Can you find a simple exact formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding a closed form for the partial sums of a sequence is a much more difficult problem than merely testing the convergence, or even finding a value for the infinite sum if it does converge. In fact, finding the exact value of an infinite sum is usually no small matter.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem